# Cross joins in results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

> Mapping:A single address id can have different tracking ids. Each tracking id and each address id will have distinct lat and long pairs. Each tracking id can have multiple route ids although most of the time it will be a single route id to tracking id mapping.

*Update: The tracking ids that I am selecting from T1_2 may or may not exist in the other tables. Also, there are no duplicates for each of the temp tables I am using for the final select statement(based on the key value).*

I am having a problem with the results of the following query.The query is supposed to produce metrics for distance deviations of delivery points from addresses. Its performing some **cross joins** on the columns and hence the **data** is **more** than it should be. I know this is related to **granularity** and is a basic mistake but its hard for me to find where I went wrong. If someone can give me some pointers,please do. A subset of the results have been attached as a link and I have also highlighted a sample tracking id which should have come only once(with only route id).The results should include address ids repeating as many times as there are distinct tracking_ids which in turn should be in sync with no_pkg column. The query is also attached for reference.
[Results subset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cyoq.png)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_stop_distance (Float, Float, Float, Float) /* This calculates distance in meters between two sets of lat and long */
       RETURNS FLOAT
     IMMUTABLE
     AS $$
       SELECT
          2 * 6373000 * ASIN( SQRT( ( SIN( RADIANS(($3 - $1) / 2) ) ) ^ 2 + COS(RADIANS($1)) * COS(RADIANS($3)) * (SIN(RADIANS(($4 - $2) / 2))) ^ 2))
     $$ LANGUAGE sql
    ;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1 AS /* This is to get top 1000 address ids which are unique identifiers for addresses in terms of orders frequency which is decided by number of distinct ordering order ids */
    SELECT destination_address_id 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT ordering_order_id)a
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT tracking_id) no_pkg
    FROM lmaa_pm.perfectmile_onroad_events_na
    where shipment_status = 'DELIVERED'              
    AND delivery_station_code = 'DCH1'
    AND event_day BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31'
    AND tracking_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY destination_address_id,delivery_station_code
    ORDER BY a DESC
    LIMIT 1000
    ;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1_2 AS /* This is to get tracking ids corresponding to those top 1000 address ids */
    SELECT DISTINCT destination_address_id
    ,tracking_id
    FROM lmaa_pm.perfectmile_onroad_events_na
    WHERE destination_address_id IN (SELECT destination_address_id FROM T1) 
    AND event_day BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31'
    AND shipment_status = 'DELIVERED'
    AND delivery_station_code = 'DCH1'
    AND tracking_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ;



    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T2 AS /* This is to get lat long pairs for addresses and delivery point respectively */
    SELECT DISTINCT gdd.lat1
    ,gdd.long1
    ,gdd.external_address_id destination_address_id
    ,gdd.tracking_id
    ,gdd.actual_lat
    ,gdd.actual_long
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY deliverydate DESC) rn /* This is to avoid duplicates since this table contains duplicates */
    FROM gtech.geocoding_data_daily_na gdd
    WHERE gdd.shipment_status_id in (51,'DELIVERED')
    AND tracking_id IN(SELECT tracking_id FROM T1_2)
    AND confidence1 = 'high'
    AND gdd.station_code='DCH1'
    AND deliverydate BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31'
    AND actual_lat IS NOT NULL
    AND actual_long IS NOT NULL
    ;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T2_2 AS
    SELECT *
    FROM T2
    WHERE rn = 1
    ;


    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T3 AS 
    SELECT T2_2.lat1
    ,T2_2.long1
    ,T2_2.actual_lat
    ,T2_2.actual_long
    ,T2_2.tracking_id
    ,T2_2.destination_address_id
    ,CASE /* This function is for identifying distance deviations in the order of 0 - 10 metres, 10-20 metres and so on */
    WHEN f_stop_distance(lat1,long1,actual_lat,actual_long) <=10 THEN '0_to_10'
    WHEN f_stop_distance(lat1,long1,actual_lat,actual_long) >10 
    and  f_stop_distance(lat1,long1,actual_lat,actual_long) <=20 THEN '10_to_20'
    WHEN f_stop_distance(lat1,long1,actual_lat,actual_long)>20
    and f_stop_distance(lat1,long1,actual_lat,actual_long) <=50 THEN '20_to_50'
    WHEN f_stop_distance(lat1,long1,actual_lat,actual_long) >50 THEN 'gt_50'
    END AS Dev_from_address
    FROM T2_2
    ORDER BY T2_2.tracking_id
    ;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T4 AS /* Doing some percentage calculations based on the new buckets created in the previous temp table namely percentage calculations out of total  */
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Dev_from_address = '0_to_10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)a
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Dev_from_address = '10_to_20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)b
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Dev_from_address = '20_to_50' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)c
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Dev_from_address = 'gt_50' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)d
          ,tracking_id
          ,(a/(a+b+c+d)::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100) AS e
          ,(b/(a+b+c+d)::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100) AS f
          ,(c/(a+b+c+d)::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100) AS g
          ,(d/(a+b+c+d)::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100) AS h
    FROM T3
    GROUP BY tracking_id
    ;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T5 AS /* adding info for route id to the existing data */
    SELECT DISTINCT route_id
    ,tracking_id
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY DATE DESC) rnnn /* to avoid duplicates */
    FROM omw.route_actuals_na
    WHERE tracking_id IN (SELECT tracking_id FROM T1_2)
    AND stop_type = 'Dropoff'
    AND scan_status  = 'DELIVERED'
    ;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T5_final AS
    SELECT *
    FROM T5
    WHERE rnnn = 1
    ;

    /* final select */
    SELECT  DISTINCT T1_2.destination_address_id
    ,T3.lat1
    ,T3.long1
    ,T3.actual_lat
    ,T3.actual_long
    ,T3.Dev_from_address
    ,T1_2.tracking_id
    ,T1.no_pkg 
    ,T4.e
    ,T4.f
    ,T4.g
    ,T4.h
    ,T5_final.route_id
    FROM T3
    JOIN T4 ON T4.tracking_id = T3.tracking_id
    JOIN T1 ON T1.destination_address_id = T3.destination_address_id
    JOIN T1_2 ON T1_2.destination_address_id = T3.destination_address_id
    JOIN T5_final ON T5_final.tracking_id = T3.tracking_id
    ORDER BY T1_2.destination_address_id
```

Comment: Too much. Simplify! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think I can do that, I am still a beginner :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strictly - no full cross joins there - however you may have a many to many join.
To track this down try taking a look at each of your joins to see whether you have >1 key value

```
select tracking_id,count(*) from t4 group by 1 having count(*) > 1;
select destination_address_id,count(*) from t1 group by 1 having count(*) > 1;
select tracking_id ,count(*) from t5_final group by 1 having count(*) > 1;
```

where you have values returned, that could be your cause. this may help you identify where you have a many to many join.